# If statement checking two inputs, a checkbox is checked and the value of an input in max length

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, if-statement, frontend

I have two inputs in the html and in JavaScript, I am trying to write a function that does a check for both inputs to show the button. The user needs to enter 7 text and check the box for the button to appear.

```js
$(document).on("input", "#activationCode", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  //Only enable button if the activation code is 7 characters
  let checkbox = document.getElementById("checkbox");
  if ($(this).val().length == 7 && checkbox.checked) {
    $('.kit-activation-button').attr('disabled', false);
  } else {
    $('.kit-activation-button').attr('disabled', true);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="activationCode" name="code" class="form-control required" required aria-required="true" maxlength="7">

<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" />

<button type="submit" class=" btn btn-primary" id="Button" disabled>submit</button>
```

I tried this but I still cant get the disable attribute to disappear when you enter 7 characters and check the box.

Comment: There's no `id="activation-pwn-check"` in the HTML. Did you mean `document.getElementById("checkbox")`?

Comment: Your event handler only runs when the user enters into the text field. You need to run it also when they check the box if they enter the code first.

Comment: Use your developer tools. Error message is clearly display when you run the code.

Comment: form validation is not your enemy, you must use it!

Comment: You are inconsistent in your usage of the closing slash. Not a fix but note that the [<input>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-input-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.

Answer (score 1):

`id="checkbox"` should be `id="activation-pwn-check"`, and `id="Button"` should be `id="kit-activation-button"`.

Move the code that enables the submit button into its own function. Then you can call it from event handlers for both the text input and checkbox.

```js
function enableDisableSubmit() {
  let checkbox = $("#activation-pwn-check");
  let textfield = $("#activationCode");
  $('#kit-activation-button').attr('disabled', !(checkbox.prop('checked') && textfield.val().length == 7));
}

$(document).on("input", "#activationCode", enableDisableSubmit);

$(document).on("change", "#activation-pwn-check", enableDisableSubmit);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="activationCode" name="code" class="form-control required" required aria-required="true" maxlength="7">

<input type="checkbox" id="activation-pwn-check" />

<button type="submit" class=" btn btn-primary" id="kit-activation-button" disabled>submit</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not naming your class `.kit-activation-button` on your element, so you're not calling anything.  Also you are not checking the state of your checkbox on activation (checked unchecked)

You can simplify this by making a function for the redundant code, but I felt long hand was a better explanation to show where the short-comings were.

```js
$(document).on("input", "#activationCode", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if ($(this).val().length == 7 && $("#checkbox").is(":checked")) {
    $('.kit-activation-button').attr('disabled', false);
  } else {
    $('.kit-activation-button').attr('disabled', true);
  }
});

$(document).on('click', "#checkbox", function() {
  if ($("#activationCode").val().length == 7 && $("#checkbox").is(":checked")) {
    $('.kit-activation-button').attr('disabled', false);
  } else {
    $('.kit-activation-button').attr('disabled', true);
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="activationCode" name="code" class="form-control required" required aria-required="true" maxlength="7">

<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" />

<button type="submit" class="kit-activation-button btn btn-primary" id="Button" disabled>submit</button>
```

A simplified version would be:

```
$(document).on("input", "#activationCode", function() {
  checkInput();
}).on('click', "#checkbox", function() {
  checkInput();
});


function checkInput(){
  $('.kit-activation-button').attr('disabled', 
  ($("#activationCode").val().length == 7 
     && $("#checkbox").is(":checked")) ? false : true);
}
```